# BeautifulSoup finding xml tags

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, openstreetmap

I've got some OSM data of fast food restaurants which I retrieved using the [Xapi](http://open.mapquestapi.com/xapi/), and [here](http://open.mapquestapi.com/xapi/api/0.6/node%5Bamenity=fast_food%5D%5Bbbox=-77.03299606884731,38.88960821016589,-77.01582993115268,38.8971235910255%5D) are  some sample results:

```
<osm version="0.6" generator="Osmosis SNAPSHOT-r26564">
   <node id="486275964" version="4" timestamp="2010-05-03T08:21:42Z" uid="12055" user="aude" changeset="4592597" lat="38.8959533" lon="-77.0212458">
      <tag k="name" v="Potato Valley Cafe"/>
      <tag k="amenity" v="fast_food"/>
   </node>
   <node id="486275966" version="4" timestamp="2010-08-06T16:44:13Z" uid="207745" user="NE2" changeset="5418228" lat="38.8959399" lon="-77.0196338">
      <tag k="cuisine" v="burger"/>
      <tag k="name" v="McDonald's"/>
      <tag k="amenity" v="fast_food"/>
   </node>
   <node id="612190923" version="1" timestamp="2010-01-12T14:01:27Z" uid="111209" user="cov" changeset="3603297" lat="38.893683" lon="-77.0292732">
      <tag k="level" v="-1"/>
      <tag k="cuisine" v="sandwich"/>
      <tag k="name" v="Quizno's"/>
      <tag k="amenity" v="fast_food"/>
   </node> 
</osm>
<!--corrected indentation-->
```

I'm trying to used BeautifulSoup in python to extract the lat, long, name and cuisine from this. I can get the lat and long no problem with this code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(results)
takeaways = soup.findAll('node')

for eachtakeaway in takeaways:
    longitude = str(eachtakeaway['lon'])
    lattitude = str(eachtakeaway['lat'])
```

But I can't get the name:

```
name = str(eachtakeaway['name'])
```

Which throws up the error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Can you tell me what to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, the square brackets are to retrieve attributes of a tag, ie `lat` and `lon`. Name, however, is an attribute of another tag. Try something like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(results)
takeaways = soup.findAll('node')

for eachtakeaway in takeaways:
    another_tag = eachtakeaway('tag')
    for tag_attrs in another_tag:
        if str(tag_attrs['k']) == 'cuisine':
            print str(tag_attrs['v'])
```

This will return the cuisine value. The same concept applies for retrieving `name`.

*Untested

Comment: bs4 has an xml mode.  Any ideas around why I would use xml mode in an instance like this?

Comment: @kalu My bs4 experience is limited, but I'm under the impression that xml mode in bs4 supports xml namespaces, case-sensitive tag handling, and other xml-specifics. I can't guarantee this as I'm only drawing from conversations with friends/colleagues and haven't researched the matter.

Answer (score 2):

The `<node>` elements do not have a `name` attribute. A child tag of the tag does:

```
for eachtakeaway in takeaways:
    longitude = str(eachtakeaway['lon'])
    lattitude = str(eachtakeaway['lat'])
    nametag = eachtakeaway.find('tag', k='name')
    name = str(nametag['v']) if nametag is not None else ''
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> takeaways = soup.findAll('node')
>>> for eachtakeaway in takeaways:
...     nametag = eachtakeaway.find('tag', k='name')
...     print str(nametag['v']) if nametag is not None else ''
... 
Potato Valley Cafe
McDonald's
Quizno's
```